# Cluster algebras of type A and X

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, hyperbolic-geometry, riemann-surfaces, cluster-algebras

I will base my question on Fock and Goncharov's paper [Dual Teichmüller and lamination spaces](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0510312).

Let $S$ be a surface with boundaries, marked points on such boundaries, punctures and boundaries without marked points. We collectively call punctures and unmarked boundaries *holes*.

To $S$ we can associate two Teichmüller spaces, let me call them $T_A(S)$ and $T_X(S)$.
The first is the decorated Teichmüller space, where above each puncture and marked point is made a choice of a horocycle. In this case all holes must be punctures.
The second is the usual Teichmüller space, and we now allow un-marked boundaries.

We define a triangulation $T$ of $S$ to be a triangulation of the surface obtained by replacing each hole with a puncture.

Associated to a triangulation $T$ of $S$ there are coordinate systems for both $T_A(S)$ and $T_X(S)$. They are positive numbers associated to the edges $e$ of $T$ and to the non-boundary edges of $T$ respectively. They are given by $\lambda$-lengths for $T_A(S)$ (indicated by $\lambda_e$) and by shear coordinates for $T_X(S)$ (indicated by $x_e$).

There is a map $T_A(S) \to T_X(S)$, which I will call the *shear map*, which is given in coordinates by $x_e = \frac{\lambda_a \lambda_c}{\lambda_b \lambda_d}$, for each inner edge $e$ belonging to triangles $[e,a,b]$ and $[e,c,d]$ of $T$.

This map lands in the subspace $\prod_{e \in p} x_e = 1$, where the product is taken over all edges $e$ incident to a hole $p$. This is a subspace of $T_X(S)$ because in general this product gives the exponential of the hyperbolic length of the hole.

**QUESTION**

Is it possible to define a "natural" map $T_A(S) \to T_X(S)$ that doesn't land in this subspace?
By "natural" I mean that it does not depend on any choice of triangulation.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is a natural extension of these ideas by considering an infinite spiralling horocycle at the hole.

One generalizes $\lambda$-lengths by adding to each an index that represents on which level of the spiral we are.

The shear map is built by taking cross ratios respecting the spiral levels.

Comment: Have you read Fomin-Shapiro-Thurston's second paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1210.5569 ? I think this spiraling construction appears there. (I don't know the answer to your question, though.)

Comment: I thought they replace the puncture with a boundary with a marked point.

Comment: I'll admit I wrote this comment without rereading the paper, on the basis of a conversation I remember with Dylan, near when the paper come out, when he drew the infinite spiral for me. Let me see if I can find it in the paper.

Comment: See Figure 23 (I still haven't reread the paper; just skimmed looking for the picture Dylan drew).